# Knockout JS: Control Serialisation of Custom Object inside ViewModel

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I recently came across this little gem of a blog post outlining a nice way to control [object serialisation in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html).

However, I am trying to apply this principle to custom objects which form properties on the main ViewModel.

For example (parts lifted from the referenced link):

```
function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = ko.observable(first);
    this.last = ko.observable(last);
    this.full = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        return this.first() + " " + this.last();
    }, this);

    this.educationCollege = new ko.educationVariable();
    this.educationSchool = new ko.educationVariable();
}

Person.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var copy = ko.toJS(this);
    delete copy.full;
    return copy; 
};

ko.educationVariable = function() {
    return {
        institution: ko.observable(),
        grade: ko.observable()
    };
};

ko.educationVariable.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var copy = ko.toJS(this);
    return copy.institution + ": " + copy.grade;
};
```

As you can see, the serialisation of `Person` is controlled via the prototype `toJSON` override and this works flawlessly.

However, you will also note that `Person` has two properties of the custom `ko.educationVariable` type.

I would like all such properties to be serialised by the respective override in `ko.educationVariable.prototype.toJSON` - but this is not working.

Since it looks like this override-feature does not work with "nesting", is there another way to control serialisation for all instances of a specific object, **other** than moving all the logic into the main ViewModel's toJSON override?

Comment: small fix makes it work check this repro ; http://jsfiddle.net/FE4HX/154/ . let me know anything apart .

Comment: By way of explanation: your educationVariable isn't a constructor (doesn't use `new`), so its objects aren't associated with prototypes.

Comment: Thanks both. I didn't think that returning `{}` vs. `this` would solve it - this one is down to my fundamental misunderstanding of JavaScript/prototype, I suppose. Anyhow, thanks for setting me straight! I'm off to read the Mozilla documentation now...